# How long until a random word with letters "A", "B", "C" ends in the pattern "ABC"?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, martingales

Let's say I have word constructed from random letters, `A` `B`and `C` with $\mathbf{P}(A) = \mathbf{P}(B) = \mathbf{P}(C) = \frac{1}{3}$.  I am going to do a random trial and record the letters I got.  The experiment stops the first time I spell out the word `ABC`.  Let $N$ be the number of trials until I make the word `ABC` out of letters.

Here are some trial words:

```
BBBBACCCCBABAABBBBCBCCBBBCACBCAACBABC
BBACCCCACABABC
CBBCCCABBABC
BABBBCAAAABC
CBBBCCBCCABABC
CCBCBBABC
ACCACCCCBCBBBCBACCBBAABBABBACCCBCBAABC
ABAAABBBABC
ABABC
BBCACAACCACCAABAAABBCABBBBACABACBACBAABACCCBCBCCCBCCCBAAAABC
```

I am asking for the expected length of this word.  And the variance.

- $\mathbb{E}[N]$ expectation
- $\mathbb{E}[N^2] - \mathbb{E}[N]^2$ variance

---

Sounding more like a textbook:

Our random variable is $X \in \{ A,B,C\}$ where each letter appears with equal probability.  Let's examine the sequence $(X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots , X_n)$ where $X_i$ are iid random variables with probability the same as $X$.  Our process stops at time $t = N$ when $(X_{N-2}, X_{N-1}, X_N) = (A,B,C)$.  What is the expected value of $N$ ?

Comment: This is a classical problem which can be solved using Markov chains. Do you know Markov chains?

Comment: Markov chains and [De Bruijn graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph).

Comment: In this sort of model (identical independent trials with finitely many outcomes), for any string like ABC in which no proper initial segment is equal to a final segment, the expected waiting time is just 1 /( frequency of the string), where the frequency is the product of the probabilities of the outcomes in the string, in this case $(1/3)(1/3)(1/3) = 1/27$.

Answer (score 9):

Expectation is easy enough (Variance seems like more work).

We have four states, according to how much of $ABC$ is complete.  Thus the states are $\emptyset, A, AB, ABC$.  Of course, Start is $\emptyset$ and End is $ABC$.  For a state $\mathscr S$ we denote by $E[\mathscr S]$ the expected number of steps, given that you are starting from $\mathscr S$.  The answer you want is $E[\emptyset]$.

We note that $$E[AB]=1\times \frac 13+(E[A]+1)\times \frac 13+(E[\emptyset]+1)\times \frac 13$$

$$E[A]=(E[AB]+1)\times \frac 13+ (E[A]+1)\times \frac 13+(E[\emptyset]+1)\times \frac 13$$

$$E[\emptyset]=(E[A]+1)\times \frac 13+(E[\emptyset]+1)\times \frac 23$$

Solving this linear system (and trusting that no arithmetic errors have been made) yields:  $$E[AB]=18\quad E[A]=24\quad \boxed {E[\emptyset]=27}$$

Comment: The math is correct, of course, but the expected length of the string needs a second look. Limiting case: Suppose there was only one letter `A`, with probability 1; what does your formula give for the expected length of a string that ends with `AAA`? ;-)

Comment: @alexis  It gives $3$, of course..  In that case there are, as before, four states, $\emptyset, A,AA, AAA$.  We have $E[AA]=1\times 1, E[A]=(E[AA]+1)\times 1, E[\emptyset]=(E[A]+1)\times 1\implies E[\emptyset]=3$.

Comment: Heh, indeed, I was thinking only of the transition probabilities! Sorry... at least it's added support for your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Once you spot that this is a Markov chain (as correctly tagged) the problem is easy to solve with first step analysis. 
States: $0, A, AB, ABC$, meaning that the ending of the word you already have is not helpful (equivalent to the empty word), ends with $A$, ends with $AB$ and ends with $ABC$, respectively. The state $ABC$ is the only absorbing state. 
Transitions:

$0\rightarrow 0$ if you get $B$ or $C$, so the transition probability is $2/3$.

$0\rightarrow A$ if you get $A$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

$A\rightarrow 0$ if you get $C$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

$A\rightarrow A$ if you get $A$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

$A\rightarrow AB$ if you get $B$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

$AB\rightarrow 0$ if you get $B$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

$AB\rightarrow A$ if you get $A$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

$AB\rightarrow ABC$ if you get $C$, so the transition probability is $1/3$.

So the transition matrix is

$\begin{pmatrix}
2/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Can you finish from here? There is a formula that computes the expected number of steps from each transient state given the transition matrix.

Answer (score 3):

For the variance, one step analysis is not enough. Basically, you need to know the probability $p_n$ that you make exactly $n$ steps starting from the empty word. It is easiest to do by finding the vector $v_n$ with length 4 whose $i$-th entry represents the probability that after $n$ steps you are in state $i$. If you had an $ABC$ somewhere, you stay in the fourth state (ABC) forever.

Then $v_0= (1, 0, 0, 0)$, and $v_{n+1}=v_n\cdot P$, where $P$ is tmatrix in my first answer:

$P= \begin{pmatrix}
2/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

So $v_n=v_0\cdot P^n$. You can compute this by standard linear algebraic techniques: compute the Jordan normal $J=S^{-1}AS$ form of $P$ (together with $S$), then exponentiation is easy, and $P^n= SJ^nS^{-1}$.

Once you have a closed form for $v_n$, add the first three coordinates: that is the probability that the length of the word is at least $n$. Denoting this by $q_n$ (it will be a linear combination of geometric series, well, almost...), we have $p_n= q_n-q_{n+1}$ (still a linear combination of geometric series, if you are lucky). Then you can compute the variance from definition, but I suggest you use the moment generating function, instead. Or just use the formulas here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Variance_on_number_of_visits

Comment: Did you manage to finish the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick simulation in R resulting in the mean of the distribution of lengths of about 27.1 (variance 591) and so confirming the result of @lulu.

```
mc = function( state ){

  if( state == '0' ){
      if( runif(1,0,1) < 1/3 ) { return('A') } else{ return('0')}
  }

  if( state == 'A' ){
      u = runif(1,0,1)
      if( u < 1/3 ) { return('A') }
      if( u < 2/3 ) { return( 'AB') } else { return('0') }
  }

  if( state == 'AB' ){
      u = runif(1,0,1)
      if( u < 1/3 ) { return('A') }
      if( u < 2/3 ) { return('0') } else { return('ABC') }
  }
}

state = '0'; nsim = 1000000;
n.abc = 0; d.abc = NULL

for( i in 1:nsim){

   state = mc( state )
   n.abc = n.abc + 1

   if( state == 'ABC' ){
      d.abc = append( d.abc, n.abc )
      n.abc = 0
      state = '0'
   }
}

d.abc = unlist( d.abc )
print( mean( d.abc ))
hist( d.abc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the apparatus of Markov chains, the result for the mean can be immediately obtained using [Kac's theorem about return times](http://bactra.org/notebooks/recurrence-times.html) (an important result that is often used, eg, for proving asympotic optimality of Lempel-Ziv compression algorithms - see eg Cover & Thomas, 13.5).

In this case, the probability of success of the ergodic $0$-$1$ process is $p=(1/3)^3=1/27$, hence the mean return time is $\langle T \rangle = 1/p=27$

The computation of the variance seems to be much more difficult. Some work in "Variations on a Theme by Mark Kac" (P. W. Kasteleyn , Journal of Statistical Physics, Vol. 46, Nos. 5/6, 1987).