# Streaks of heads/tails with Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the following problem, from Tijms's *Understanding Probability*:

> Calculate the probability of a run of five heads or five tails
>   occurring in 20 tosses of a fair coin. What is the probability of a run of five
>   heads occurring in 20 tosses of a fair coin? Do you think the following game
>   is fair? A fair coin is tossed until heads appears three times in a row. You pay
>   \$1 for each toss of the coin, but you get \$12.50 as soon as heads has appeared three times in a row.

This problem should be solvable by an absorbing Markov chain.

Let 1 be the state where in the last two tosses we had HT or TH, 2 be the state where in the last three tosses we got HTT or THH, 3 be the state HTTT or THHH in the last four tosses, 4 be the state HTTTT or THHHH in the last five tosses, 5 be the state with 5 heads or 5 tails.

The problem is equivalent to asking what is the probability of reaching state 5 in 20 steps starting from state 1.

The transition probabilities are the following:

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
because, for example, if we currently have HT (state 1), we can get to HTH (state 1) with probability $1/2$, and to HTT (state 2) with probability $1/2$ (this explains the numbers in the first column of $P$).

The entry in row 5, column 1 of $P^{20}$ is 0.47802, but the book says this probability is wrong (it should be 0.4584).

As for the second problem (if the game is a fair game), I suppose that we should compute the expected number of tosses before having three heads in a row, but I am not sure on how to do this.

Edit: following the hint by lulu, for the second part of the problem I think we should proceed as follows.

Let the state 1 correspond to only one T, or to a string that ends in T, the state 2 correspond to a single H or something that ends in TH, state 3 correspond to HH or something that ends in THH, state 4 correspond to HHH or something that ends in THHH.
State 4 is absorbing.

The transition matrix is:
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(note that I use the opposite convention with respect to the first part of the problem, namely $P$ now would be $P^T$ in the first part).

Now, let $e_i$ be the expected number of tosses for reaching state 4 starting from state $i$. Clearly $e_4=0$ because if we are at state 4 we don't need to toss to arrive at state 4.

We have the following system of equations for the expected number of tosses:
$$
\begin{aligned}
e_1 &= (1+e_1)\frac12 + (1+e_2)\frac12 \\
e_2 &= (1+e_1)\frac12 + (1+e_3)\frac12 \\
e_3 &= (1+e_1)\frac12 + (1+e_4)\frac12.
\end{aligned}
$$
Replacing $e_4=0$ and solving for $e_1$, we get $e_1=14$.
So the game would be fair if the reward were of 14\$ or more, otherwise it is a losing game.

Does it sound right?

Comment: For the second problem, [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238501/how-long-until-a-random-word-with-letters-a-b-c-ends-in-the-pattern-abc/3238512#3238512) is similar, the same techniques apply here.

Comment: For the first problem, your work is fine (+1), except for one minor error. Since your specified initial state already assumes one flip, you should raise the matrix to the $19$-th power, not the $20$-th.

Comment: @quasi that's right, computing the 19-th power gives indeed 0.45840. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting with HT or TH, which consists of two flips, the full outcome of which is (HT,TH) = state 1 and (TT,HH) = state 2.
So you start with $(1/2,1/2,0,0,0)$ and multiply by $P^{18}$ , which in fact gives 
$$p(5)= \frac{240335}{524288} \approx 0.45840 \ldots$$

Comment: +1: That is a nice and quick answer