# What are the chances of getting at least one sequence of at least 5 heads or tails in a row when flipping fair coin 20 times?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I flip a fair coin 20 times and record the sequence, e.g., `h t h t h h t t h t t t t t t h t t t t`. What are the chances the sequence will contain *at least* one “run” (subsequence) of *at least* 5 heads *or* tails in a row?

### Update 1:

I could not figure out a mathematical approach, so I created an experimental one:

```
from random import randint
from fractions import Fraction as F

def ht() -> str:
    if randint(1, 2) == 1:
        return 'h'
    else:
        return 't'

def get_seq(length: int = 20) -> tuple[str]:
    x = list()
    for y in range(length):
        x.append(ht())
    return tuple(x)

def get_max_run_length(seq_length: int = 20) -> int:
    seq = get_seq(seq_length)
    previous: str = ''
    current_run: int = 0
    max_run: int = 0
    for i in seq:
        if i == previous:
            current_run += 1
        else:
            previous = i
            current_run = 1
        if current_run > max_run:
            max_run = current_run
    return max_run

def n_length_subseq_in_seq(seq_length: int = 20,
                           sub_seq_length: int = 5,
                           count_greater_seq: bool = True,
                           number_of_runs: int = 1000000) -> Fraction:
    running_count = 0
    for one_run in range(number_of_runs):
        max_run_this_test = get_max_run_length(seq_length)
        if max_run_this_test == sub_seq_length:
            running_count += 1
        elif count_greater_seq and max_run_this_test > sub_seq_length:
            running_count += 1
    print(running_count / number_of_runs)
    return F(running_count, number_of_runs)
```

Running `get_max_run_length()` consistently yields about $0.458$. How would I set this problem up mathematically?

### Update 2:

I realized that this particular question only has $2^{20} = 1048576$ possible combinations, so I could just brute force it. The answer is $\frac{240335}{524288}=0.4584026336669921875$.

I still wish I knew how to set up the problem generally.

### Update 3:

With the precise answer in hand, my Google search suddenly turned up [Streaks of heads/tails with Markov chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241262/streaks-of-heads-tails-with-markov-chains), which talks about Markov Chains, which I've never encountered. The math contains matrices, so it may be that my 20-year-old discrete math was insufficient for this task.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that it may well be easier to count the strings of a given length that do not contain a run of length $≥5$.

Comment: I don’t know how to approach the problem, so I’m not sure what efforts to show. (I haven’t been in college for almost 20 years.) I believe that because order matters, that means I’m dealing with permutations instead of combinations, but that’s about all I can remember.

Comment: So, try easier problems.  What's the probability that you never see $HH$ in $n$ tosses?  What's the probability that you never see either $HH$ or $TT$ in $n$ tosses?  And so on.  There's really no point in getting other people to solve these problems for you.  There's no shortage of worked probability problems on this site and elsewhere.  Wouldn't surprise me if this one is a duplicate.